# working with forms and ajax in drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

is it possible to alter a form after an ajax call?
what i want to do is this:
i have a form with some textfields and a select box with 2 options.
what i want to do is when a person chooses one option, i will unset some of the textfields(depends on which option the user choose).
i do this with ajax because i need to load from my DB which input to disable.
ofcouese i can hide it with jQuery(which i do).
but i was wondering that if there a way for doing it in the ajax server function.
10x.

Answer (score 0):

I would get a look to the Form API of drupal and how AHAH (Asynchronous HTML and HTTP) works [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html#ahah)
and [here](http://drupal.org/node/348475) you'll find a small example how to implement it.

Anyway you can always give a look on modules that are using it like pools, filefield (CCK), etc.

cheers :)